# QR code generator en scanner for xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, zxing

I'm new to working with qr codes in xamarin.android. I have searched the internet for answers, but I didn't found the answer that suits my requirements. I found a couple of nuget packages that I could use like:

- Zxing.net
- Zxing.mobile
- qrcoder

But I can't manage to find an example in xamarin.android. Well my question would be: what's the best library to:

- read qr codes and import the content to a string.
- generate qr code based on a string.

Does anyone have a clue which way to go?

Comment: Ggogle `read and generate qr code xamarin.android` you would find the article and sample .

Comment: To create and decode QR codes in C# Xamarin applications, you could use the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/to/qr-code-barcodes-in-leadtools.html). (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendor). [There’s a free evaluation here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) and if you install the main SDK setup, there a full demo with source code in the folder LEADTOOLS22\Examples\Barcode\Xamarin\BarcodeDemo.